# Скачивание файла k6 browser

Tags: javascript, test-automation

Как в k6/browser подтвердить скачивание файла в системном окне. Может есть возможность выдать пермишенны какие-то. Для puppeteer и playwrigth есть решения, но k6 немного ограничен в этом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]